# Conditional Content Display

Tags: php, functions

I"m trying to replace the string "Something Nice will show up here" in the block of codes below with WordPress loop but  it doesn't seem to be working. I'd like when Link1 is clicked on, let the post with the ID "intro-paragraphs" show. Any ideas on how to do that properly?

```
<?php

   $longString = "Something Nice will show up here";

    $link=$_GET['link'];
    if ($link == '1'){
         echo $longString;
    }
    if ($link == '2'){
        include 'page2.php';
    }
    if ($link == '3'){
        include 'page3.php';
    }
    if ($link == '4'){
        include 'page4.php';
    }
        ?>
```

Like this

```
<?php

$longString = "<?php


$query = new WP_Query('category_name=intro-paragraphs');


if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 


?>
    <div class="mid-box">
      <h1>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h1>
      <?php echo excerpt(40); ?><br/>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">&raquo; read more...</a> </div>
    <!-- End Mid-Box -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>";
```

Comment: sorry, but I have no clue what you're trying to accomplish here. could you perhaps explain in more detail what end result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like when Link1 is clicked on, let a satin post show.

Comment: What is a "satin post"?

Comment: Err... Are you trying to _double parse_ some PHP code? Is that even possible? Why would you want to do this (**iff** it's possible, that is)? I think, what you want to do, is either use a `function` that is generating your desired output, or just perform the specific actions under certain conditions. But anyway, as Milo and vancoder said, your question really needs some rewording as it is fairly unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can't execute PHP code from within a string.

#### You can however define a function that executes code and call that function within your if clauses.

```
function dz_slick_longstring() {
    $query = new WP_Query('category_name=intro-paragraphs');

    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="mid-box">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <?php echo excerpt(40); ?><br/>
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">&raquo; read more...</a>
        </div>
    <!-- End Mid-Box -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
}
```

Then instead of doing this:

```
if ($link == '1'){
         echo $longString;
    }
```

Do This:

```
if ($link == '1'){
        dz_slick_longstring();
    }
```

Comment: Chris thank you so much for taking your time to understand my question.